# Stratify a train / test split according to some categorical variables

Tags: stratification, train-test-split

I would like to train / test split a dataset in such a way that all categories of categorical variables are in both train and test split.

I tried ( using sickit learn ) :

```
df_moto_train , df_moto_test = train_test_split( df_moto , test_size = 0.15 , stratify = df_moto[ cols_obj ] )
```

( where cols_obj is a list of categorical variables from the dataframe df_moto )

but I got the message :

```
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error massage says it all: in some subgroups you have insufficient data. You need to gather more data or split it differently.

Comment: Right : one combination of categories has only one record. The more categorical variables you stratify on, the more you could meet that case. I wonder if there is a way to collapse categories such as to ensure stratification is possible.